# Which are ALL the requirements for implementing simple data binding in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, data-binding, user-controls

To create a custom control supporting simple data binding I followed the instructions reported by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171926.aspx) and shortly after I discovered they are incomplete. Implementing the `DefaultBindingProperty` attribute is not enough and it seems you need to have the control either (i) implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` or exposing an event named `<propertyname>Changed` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589012/how-to-have-bindable-properties-of-a-usercontrol-which-work-with-onpropertychang).

Still, my code (actually a very simplified version of it) here below does not work and I'm struggling for this since almost 1 day now. My control is:

```
[DefaultBindingProperty("Value")]
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    NumericUpDown upDown;
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        upDown = new NumericUpDown() { Minimum = 0, Maximum = 100, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        Controls.Add(upDown);
        upDown.ValueChanged += control_ValueChanged;
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)upDown.Value; }
        set { upDown.Value = (decimal)value; }
    }
    private void control_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValueChanged != null)
            ValueChanged(this, e);
    }
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;
}
```

and my test form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyUserControl myUserControl;
    BindingSource source;
    MyClass myClass;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        source = new BindingSource();
        myClass = new MyClass() { Amount = 30 };
        source.DataSource = new[] { myClass };

        myUserControl = new MyUserControl();
        Controls.Add(myUserControl);
        myUserControl.DataBindings.Add("Value", source, "Amount", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    int amount;
    public int Amount
    {
        get { return amount; }
        set
        {
            amount = value;
            MessageBox.Show("New amount: " + amount);
        }
    }
}
```

The messagebox at the end of the code is not fired when changing the value in the `NumericUpDown`. Is there another piece of information I'm missing? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems you need to have the control either implementing INotifyPropertyChanged or exposing an event named <propertyName>Changed as explained here.

These are the options when you implement a data source. For custom control the only option is the later, since the base control already is using that pattern, and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` will break it, because as stated in one of the notes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/library/41e17s4b(v=vs.110).aspx)

> For change notification to occur in a binding between a bound client and a data source your bound data-source type should either implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (preferred) or you can provide *propertyName**Changed*** events for the bound type, but you shouldn't do both.

So you correctly used the `PropertyNameChanged` pattern (or at least tried :)

> Is there another piece of information I'm missing? What am I doing wrong here?

Here are some related links - [Change Notification in Windows Forms Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/library/xz45s2bh(v=vs.110).aspx) and [How to: Apply the PropertyNameChanged Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229615(v=vs.110).aspx), but what you are missing and unfortunately seems to not to be explained anywhere in the documentation is what exactly `PropertyNameChanged` pattern is, and the key point is that in addition to the specially named event, it expects a specific **type** of that event, and more precisely, to be of type `EventHandler`. I guess now you see the problem - you have used `EventHandler<EventArgs>`. The method signature is one and the same, but the same can be said for `Action<object, EvenetArgs>`. `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` is now the recommended one, bur remember it didn't exist at the time data binding has been introduced. Etc.

Shorty, change this line

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;
```

to

```
public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
```

and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Yes it was that, many thanks! I understand that the data binding was expecting an `EventHandler` instead than an `EventHandler<EventArgs>`, but I cannot believe that at Microsoft they didn't add support for the latter when generic were introduced! Even worse I cannot find this documented anywhere and it is incredible to lose more than 1 day of work for a small flaw like this!!!